# Array replace not working

Tags: php, arrays

The below is my array, where I need to replace the value of **'battle_health'**

```
$battlepokemon= array();

$i = 1;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
$path = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM pokemons WHERE pk_id = '".$rows['pkmn_id']."' ");
$pokemon = array(
'opponent_increment' => $i,
'id' => $rows['pkmn_id'],
'battle_poke'=> mysql_result($path,0,"path"),
'battle_level' => $rows['level'],
'battle_health' => $rows['health']
);
$i++;
$battlepokemon[]= $pokemon;
}
```

The code for replacement is:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($battlepokemon as $key => $value) 
{
if($value['opponent_increment'] == $opponent_increment)
{
$value['battle_health'] = 0;
echo "Data replaced!";
}
$i++;
}
print_r($battlepokemon);
```

The code above is working..from start to end.. but the value is not replaced with '0' as the code says!
I think I must have missed something!

Comment: your replacing in the *temporary* copy of the array php creates for the loop, not the original

Comment: Where is $opponent_increment defined ? what is the value ?

Comment: change `foreach ($battlepokemon as $key => $value) ` to `foreach ($battlepokemon as $key => &$value)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to transfer the reference, not the values. Add a `&` to the following sentence

```
foreach ($battlepokemon as $key => &$value) 
                                   ^
```

I tried this just for example

```
<?php
$arr = array('12', '34');
foreach($arr as $key => &$value){
  $value = 0;
}
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Hopes it can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `for Loop` `Because unlike foreach loop, it doesn't perform an array copy before transversal`:

```
$arr = array('12', '34');
for($i = 0, $count = count($arr); $i < $count; $i++){
    $arr[$i] = 0;
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Or If you want to do with `Foreach` only, you need to avoid new copy of array by passing the `reference` like:

```
   $arr = array('12', '34');
   foreach($arr as $key => &$value)
   {
       $value = 0;
   }
   var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Downvoted as the code you supplied is quite inefficient. You can use a foreach loop, you just need force the value to be a reference (noted in another answer) or refer to the scoped array variable. You must also be careful with a `count` in your `for` loop. The second argument of your `for` loop will be executed every iteration. The more efficient code is: `for($i = 0, $count = count($arr); $i < $count; $i++)`